# Querying DocumentDB gets an "A task was canceled" error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I query DocumentDB I sometimes get an "A task was canceled" exception. The code for querying DocumentDB is the following

```
    public IOrderedQueryable<T> QueryToDb(string DatabaseId, string CollectionId)
    {
        DocumentClient dcClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentURI"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["documentKEY"]);
        Uri CollectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[DatabaseId], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CollectionId]);

        return dcClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(CollectionLink, feedOptions);
    }
```

Could this error connected someway with DocumentDB throttling? Into the exception thrown, there aren't any references to HTTP 429 status code but only "A task was canceled".

Comment: Not able to replicate error with that code. Testet with a collection with only 2 documents, so size might matter. 

How many documents do you have, what do you do with the IOrderedQueryable<T> that you return? Do you have multiple document types in your collection?

Comment: My collection has about 1000 documents. I use the returned object to make some WHERE clauses or ORDER BY. In this collection there is only one type of document.

Answer (score 1):

"A task was canceled" exception is usually due to an issue related to concurrency.

In the sample above, I noticed `QueryToDb` constructs a new Azure DocumentDB client whenever it gets called.

It is important to note that the DocumentDB client is fairly heavy, but is also thread safe.

If you have multiple threads calling `QueryToDb` - it may be possible that your application is spending too much time constructing and initializing DB clients causing async query tasks to be canceled.

It is best for multi-threaded applications to create a DocumentDB client as a singleton which gets shared across threads.

Comment: In reality the method QueryToDb does not instance a new client at every query but it uses an unique client I've declared as a static variable into the "Program" class of the console application.

Comment: How many threads do you have? Are you managing the # of threads manually or are you using a ThreadPool to managing? If you have too many threads - the runtime may spend too much time context switching and not enough time doing work, causing pending tasks to become cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes scaling up/out the consumer service can be solution.